# Should I model a problem with quantised output as classification or regression?

Tags: classification, models, regression

Say I have some data I am trying to learn, and I'm aware that the output is quantised in some way, e.g. I can get only get discrete values (0.1, 0.2, 0.3...0.9) in a finite range.

Would you treat that as regression or classification? In this case the numbers do have a relation to each other e.g. 0.3 is close to 0.4 in meaning.

I could treat it as classification with a softmax final layer with N outputs, or could treat it as regression with a linear layer with single output and then somehow quantise the result post-prediction. But my gut feeling is that the fact there is a finite number of answers that that should somehow be used in my model?

Answer (score 1):

So this is considered [Ordinal Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression). There are many ways to model this type of data, generally in some form of regression setting. I do not recommend the softmax route because as you mentioned, there exists prebuilt correlation to the outputs.

*Some common ways to approach this*
(Note that im assuming your looking for methodologies that can be optimized through gradient techniques because of the way you formulated your question)

1. Treat it as a normal regressor where you clip the output to your range, and then define thresholds arbitrarily, such as $.36 \rightarrow .4$, $.34 \rightarrow .3$, etc..
2. Use a bounded activation function then scale (if your outputs are [0,1,.1], you could use sigmoid and just scale by a factor of 1, but if [0,10,1], you could use sigmoid and scale by 10. Once again youll need to create arbitrary threshold between each 2 points for inference (this can also be incorporated into your loss)
3. Using the above two methods, but learn the threshold between each 2 ordered points. Have an output layer that learns the ideal threshold for inference

And if you didnt want to use neural netowrks, each of these approaches have a bayesian analog that work as well!